# I can't seem to figure out what to do with this instance so that my code could print out the requirement

Tags: java, constructor, instances

So the specifications are: Create a BankAccount class. It should contain the following information, stored in instance variables. 
I need to have a constructor: `BankAccount(String firstName, String lastName, double openingBalance)`. And a `public String firstName()`, a `public String lastName(),` and a `public double balance()` that return the First Name, last name and balance respectively.

And I have this so far...

```
public class BankAccountAssignmentPart1 {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double openBalance;

BankAccountAssignmentPart1 (String firstName, String lastName, double openBalance) {
    firstName = "Alfred";
    lastName = "Jones";
    openBalance = 1408;
}

public String firstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String lastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public double Balance(){
    return openBalance;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    BankAccountAssignmentPart1 m = new BankAccountAssignmentPart1();

    System.out.println(m.firstName()); 
    System.out.println(m.lastName());
    System.out.println(m.Balance());
}
```

}

So the problem I have is in the line `BankAccountAssignmentPart1 m = new BankAccountAssignmentPart1();` in Eclipse it says that the constructor is undefined and goes on to give suggestions to change the code such as removing the String String double or change the modifier to static which can't happen in instances....So I don't know what to do.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify parameters when you call your constructor:

```
BankAccountAssignmentPart1 m = new BankAccountAssignmentPart1("1","2",0);
```

Otherwise it tries to find BankAccountAssignmentPart1() constructor (with no parameters), which is indeed undefined.